# Getting the extended properties of SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query to get the extended properties of the table

```
SELECT 
    objname, objtype, [name], value, 
    pos = (CASE e.objtype  
              WHEN 'table' THEN 1 
              WHEN 'column' THEN 2 
              ELSE 3 
           END)
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         objtype, objname, name, 
         CONVERT(varchar(200), value) AS 'value'
     FROM 
         fn_listextendedproperty(null, 'user', 'dbo', 'table', 'questions', null, null)
     UNION
     SELECT 
         objtype, objname, name, 
         CONVERT(varchar(200), value) AS 'value'
     FROM 
         fn_listextendedproperty(null, 'user', 'dbo', 'table', 'questions', 'column', null)
    ) e
ORDER BY 
    pos, objname, [name];
```

but it does not seem to return the correct data.

Comment: What does it return and what do you expect it to return? (Please update your question with additional info, instead of typing it as a comment).

Comment: it extended properties i defined for the table

Comment: What properties have you defined? Remember, we know nothing of your system setup.

Comment: Are you passing real values to the function?